# How to show that any two non-parallel vectors can form the basis of $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How would you go about showing that any two non-parallel vectors can form the basis of $\Bbb R^2$? I know that they will do: they form a linearly independent set because neither are multiples of each other (due to them being non-parallel), so they will form a basis. The vector space defined by this basis will have two dimensions as there are two basis vectors.

However, I am not sure that it is enough to simply state this-- are there any other ways of showing it?

Comment: Look up "Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have touched on the Gram-Schmidt procedure briefly before, but I am not sure how I can use it to help me in this case?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt (for two non-parallel vectors) creates two perpendicular vectors... precisely what you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that any $2$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

More generally, we have the following fact: If $v_1, \dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent, then $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

To prove this, we need the following fundamental lemma: If $v_1, \dots, v_{n + 1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $v_1, \dots, v_{n + 1}$ are linearly dependent. This can be proved by induction on $n$. The cases $n = 0$, $n = 1$ are easy. The case $n = 2$ is more difficult, but gives the idea for the inductive step.

With the lemma, we can prove the fact. Suppose $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are linearly independent. We need to show that $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose it doesn't. Then there exists $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $w \notin \text{span}\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$. It is easy to show that $v_1, \dots, v_n, w$ are linearly independent. But this contradicts the lemma. Thus $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
 d/(ad-bc) & -b/(ad-bc) \\ -c/(ad-bc) & a/(ad-bc)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

The above matrix shows how the $(1,0)$ and the $(0,1)$ vectors can be formed from a linear combination of $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$.

You get $(1,0) = d/(ad-bc) (a,c) -c/(ad-bc)(b,d)$,

and $(0,1) = -b/(ad-bc)(a,c) +a/(ad-bc)(b,d)$.

Answer (score 0):

The two vectors say $u,v$, cannot be linearly dependent because then $au+bv=0$ where $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$. Now wlog we can assume a is nonzero and so $u=-(b/a)v$ which means they are in fact parallel.

Now you can try proving that any $n$ linearly independent vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space is in fact a basis.

Comment: How do I go about beginning to prove that? I don't want the full proof, I just don't know where to start